# RPi3 and Python3

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3

As of now I am running python 3.4.2 on my RPi under Raspbian 8.0 Jessie.  However, this seems outdated.  Checking the official Python website 3.4.2 is listed as from 2014.  I would like to update to 3.6.1.  How would I go about doing this?  I'm quite a beginner but know my way around the terminal somewhat, not a complete noob.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do that you can't do in 3.4? If you want to use the latest software forget Raspbian, which is based on Debian. This is a conservative distribution, well tested and safe but usually well behind the cutting edge.

Comment: I see.  I just started with Python so I suppose you're right, I don't really need bleeding-edge.  I'll stick with what I got.  Thanks!